# Python - Django query using auth.User model as OneToOneField

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-users

I am using the `auth.User` model for login info, and a custom `UserProfile` model for all of a user's profile data.

The `auth.User.username` is a random string.
and the `UserProfile`.user is the same string.

When attempting to query the database table "`UserProfile`" I get the following error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '3df69698-c97d-11e7-a924-b0c0905e8512'
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=256, default=None)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=256, default=None)
    ...

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)
```

views.py

```
from .models import UserProfile
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def get_users(request):
    data = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
    user_id = escape(data['id'])

    # error occurs here
    user_pref = UserProfile.objects.get(user=user_id)
```

The problem comes when trying to query the database, and using a string compared to an `auth.User` object. I do not know how to get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that string supposed to be the username? If so you should query that field explicitly:

```
UserProfile.objects.get(user__username=user_id)
```

Comment: Yes, I get it now, I was querying the entire User object accidentally...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this:

```
UserProfile.objects.get(user__user_id=user_id)
```

Comment: That gives a new error:  `Related Field got invalid lookup: user_id`

Comment: You were right, but as Daniel said, username from the auth.User model!